# Aviary integration Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, aviary

I am integrating Aviary into my application and getting a crash when i try to present `AFPhotoEditorController` into one of my View Controller.

```
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions];
    });

    // Initialize the photo editor and set its delegate

    AFPhotoEditorController * photoEditor = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:editingResImage];
    [photoEditor setDelegate:self];

    // If a high res image is passed, create the high res context with the image and the photo editor.
        if (highResImage) {
            [self setupHighResContextForPhotoEditor:photoEditor withImage:highResImage];
        }

    // Present the photo editor.
    //This is the line on which i am getting crash
    [self presentViewController:photoEditor animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is the actual stack trace

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/CB39553D-8CA9-425C-BF5E-B33DD5813CA9/KidstaGram.app/AviarySDKResources.bundle> (not yet loaded)' with name 'AFSDKViewController_iPhone_4_inch_7''

 First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x027055e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024888b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x027053bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x0149b65c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
    4   UIKit                               0x0130dc95 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    5   UIKit                               0x0130e43d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    6   UIKit                               0x0130e73e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    7   UIKit                               0x0130ec44 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x0131d9f1 -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 63
    9   UIKit                               0x01315590 -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 84
    10  UIKit                               0x015a321a -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 5199
    11  UIKit                               0x0131a78c -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6433
    12  UIKit                               0x0fcb9f1f -[UIViewControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x0131acaf -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    14  KidstaGram                          0x00029f9c -[UploadViewController launchPhotoEditorWithImage:highResolutionImage:] + 412
    15  KidstaGram                          0x00029d0f -[UploadViewController launchEditorWithAsset:] + 191
    16  KidstaGram                          0x0002b3fb __76-[UploadViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]_block_invoke_2 + 107
    17  AssetsLibrary                       0x0077f639 __56-[ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 215
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x068f0818 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x069054b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x068f3766 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0276aa5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x026ab72b __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x026aab33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x026aa94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x037069d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x037067fe GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x011fb94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  KidstaGram                          0x00015fbd main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x06b95725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: check with this nib file `AFSDKViewController_iPhone_4_inch_7`. this could not be find, that's error according to first line?

Comment: @Mani, aviary sdk includes only the header files.

Comment: I solved this problem by setting the linker flags as -ObjC and -all_load.

Comment: i have accidentally copy AviarySDKResources.bundle into Build settings>Link Library with Setting rather than copy it into Build Settings>copy bundle Resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update to the latest version of the SDK on the Aviary website : [developers.aviary.com](http://developers.aviary.com). Additionally, please also make sure that you updated both the .framework file in addition to the .bundle

Answer (score 0):

if you using AdobeCreativeSDK it will help you. 
First we need to open AdobeCreativeSDKImage.framework and from that go to resources folder and copy AdobeCreativeSDKImageResources.bundle and paste that in project directory after that add it to the project

In the same way first we need to open AdobeCreativeSDKFoundation.framework and from that go to resources folder and copy AdobeCreativeSDKFoundationResources.bundle and paste that in project directory after that add it to the project